# Rails gem installed but throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rbenv

Looks like i have a problem trying to install rails gem.

so i followed the steps from [this tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04), 
I am using Ubuntu 14.04, rbenv and ruby version 2.2.3

Basically my error is:

apparently I installed rails gem successfully

$ gem install rails -v 4.2.4

-> `Successfully installed rails-4.2.4`

but whenever i try to use rails command, for example:

$ rails -v

-> `bin/rails:9:in require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from bin/rails:9:in < main >'`

And got the same result for any other rails command

I searched everywhere and noone seem to have the same problem as I do. 
I dont really know what to do now, any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

---

UPDATE: apparently when I enter to a previously created rails app and try to run a rails command, this happens:

```
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

so after I run `bundle install` everything works normally as it should... but if I leave the folder, then I am no longer able to use rails anymore, so I cannot create a new rails app or anything

Comment: What's the output of rbenv versions?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are sitting inside of a Rails repository already, since there is a `bin/rails`. So try running `bundle install` first---and if necessary `gem install bundler` before that.

Comment: Yes, i had that problem before, I was in home folder but whenever I tried to make a new rails app, the terminal kept telling me i was already in a rails repository. But, already tried that, it didnt work, so i uninstalled rails and rbenv and installed it again, still not working tho

Answer (score 0):

I believe rails gem is not installed into your gemset try installing rails gem to gemset with :

```
sudo gem install rails
```

If problem still persists then may be your installations are not good & I recommend you to follow this [Link](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/installing-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-1404/) to install ruby through rvm and then install rails gem to your gemset it will work.

```
Open console
Select Edit -> Profile Preferences
Select tab: Title and Command
Check box 'Run command as a login shell'
Restart terminal
and try rvm use 2.2.1 --default
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried it... didnt work. I got the same result

Comment: Try `rvm use 2.2.1` or smaller version which is installed in your system you can check with : `rvm list`. then try running rails command.

Comment: the output  is:
$ rvm use 2.2.1


-> `RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use '/bin/bash --login' as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for an example.`

Comment: so I tried logging in using `/bin/bash --login` and then `rvm use 2.2.1`, apparently it works, but when logging out with `exit`, rvm tells me ruby-2.3.0 is still in use.

Comment: Also I tried changing my terminal profile preferences, but problem still persist

Comment: alright, now my default ruby is 2.2.1
`rvm rubies

=> ruby-2.2.1 [ x86_64 ]`

but im still having the same problem with rails, any other ideas? thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
gem install rails --no-rdoc --no-ri
```